# Html5 conditional statements for old versions of chrome and firefox?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, browser

I'm using angular js and have currently done the condition for ie8 and older.

I need help for doing the same for chrome and firefox.

**This is my current IE condition:**

```
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <p>You are using an outdated browser.</p>
        <![endif]-->
```

I need to do the same condition but for less than chrome version 46 and for less than firefox version 44.

Thanks,